# Turning a 2D array into a sparse array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `x=[[3,1],[2,2]]` and I want to turn it into `x[3][1]=1` and `x[2][2]=1`. The code should also work for longer arrays like `x=[[3,1],[2,12],[3,3]]`.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. `x=[[3,1],[2,2]]` *is* a 2D array. What you are asking for is to convert an array of arrays into a sparse array of arrays.

Comment: An "array of arrays" is a 2D array

Comment: It is still possible to covert the [[3,1],[2,2]] to x[3][1] and x[2][2]

Comment: Ignoring the terminology, can you provide code to change the 2D array into a sparse array of arrays

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg Speaking of terminology, i would then say converting an array of arrays into a sparse array of sparse arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you take two inputs: `pos0`, `pos1`

```
for (i in x)  
    if (x[i][0] == pos0 && x[i][1] == pos1) {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

So it basically checks each index

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and create a new array, if not already. Then assign the value to the given index.

This solution takes a new array for the result.

```js
var x = [[3, 1], [2, 12], [3, 3]],
    result = [];

x.forEach(function (a) {
    result[a[0]] = result[a[0]] || [];
    result[a[0]][a[1]] = 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var x = [[3,1],[2,12],[3,3]],
    r = x.reduce((p,c) => (p[c[0]] ? p[c[0]][c[1]] = 1
                                   : p[c[0]] = Array.from({[c[1]]: 1, length: c[1]+1}),
                           p),[]);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = [[3,1], [2,2]]

console.log('x =', x)

// Initialize 1st dimension array
const y = []
for (let i in x) {
  // Initialize the 2nd dimension array if not exist
  y[x[i][0]] = y[x[i][0]] || []
  // Assign the value to the sparse array
  y[x[i][0]][x[i][1]] = 1
}

console.log('y =', y)
```

Output:

```
x = [ [ 3, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ] ]
y = [ , , [ , , 1 ], [ , 1 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to iterate through your array and check if the array exist corresponding to first value, in case it's not initialise with `[]` and then assign the value to that index.

```js
var x=[[3,1],[2,12],[3,3]];
var result = x.reduce((r,[a,b]) => {
  r[a] = r[a] || [];
  r[a][b] = 1;
  return r;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```